# How can i re-render react component with infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks, setinterval, use-effect

I want update the toggle state after 3 sec. this code sometime it works sometimes won't work. setinterval call callback function twice and and much more.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import matrix from '../../../assets/videos/matrix.mp4'
import '../../../css/header-banner.css'
import TextAnimation from '../../Components/custom/TextAnimation';
const HeaderBanner = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
    const textAnimation = ():void => {
        // setToggle(!toggle)
        console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
        
    }

    setInterval(textAnimation, 3000)
    // console.log(toggle);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="header-banner">
                <video className='' autoPlay loop muted>
                    <source src={matrix}/>
                </video>
                <div className="header-overlay bg-green-800">
                    <div className="banner-text">
                        {
                            <TextAnimation toggle={toggle} text='Hack the World!'/>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HeaderBanner;
```

Comment: Call your `setInterval` inside of a `useEffect` hook and refactor your `textAnimation ` function into a `callback` hook.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is an effect and needs to be run in [useEffect](https://go.dev/tour/methods/23). Don't forget to [clean up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) the interval when the component unmounts.　Here's a minimal, verifiable example. <kbd>Run</kbd> the code below and click the <kbd>toggle</kbd> button to start/stop the interval timer.

```js
function App() {
  const [animating, toggleAnimating] = useToggle(false)
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    if (animating) {
      const t = window.setInterval(console.log, 1000, "animate!")
      return _ => window.clearInterval(t)　// ✅ clean up
    }
  }, [animating])
  return <div>
    <button onClick={toggleAnimating} children={`toggle: ${animating ? "OFF" : "ON"}`} />
    <pre>{JSON.stringify({ animating })}</pre>
  </div>
}

function useToggle(initState = false) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initState)
  return [value, _ => setValue(!value)]
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```